# Find files with R console

Tags: r, file, matrix

there is the list.file function and a pattern in the function. However, how can i find things in a fold if it has the ending yto and within the name there is a 111 (it has to be before the dot)?

Comment: The function is `list.files` and you pass a regex to the `pattern` parameter that matches the file names you want. See `help("regex")` or many introductions and tutorials out there.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

As @Roland writes, you can use the `list.files` function. Run `?list.files` for the documentation hereof.

Say we wish to list all `.txt` files in foldes (and subfolders). Then something like

```
list.files(pattern = "\\.txt$", recursive = TRUE)
```

would do the trick. The `recursive` argument makes the function search subfolders as well. The `pattern` we're looking for the regular expression `"\\.txt$"` meaning that the filename should end with `.txt`. Consult `?regex` for more information on regular expressions.

**EDIT**: If you search for files which ends in `111.tx` you then need to modify the above to:

```
list.files(pattern = "111\\.tx$", recursive = TRUE)
```

Comment: the whol thing is it need to be .tx and the name has to have 111 before that it is a file liek fsdjgdsfkjhk111.tx..you se?

Comment: @kagh I've edited my answer to what I *think* you mean.